# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) on my project

Tags: php, laravel

hello i have problem with my project

```
public function toUpper($plain){
        $upper = strtoupper($plain);
        $pos = strpos($plain,$upper);
        $length = strlen($plain,$upper);
        if($pos !== false && $pos == 0){
            return $upper.substr($plain, $length);
        }else{
            return $upper.$plain;
        }
    }
```

and my problem on

```
$upper = strtoupper($plain);
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: Is this in a class?

Comment: "_Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)_" says your problem is (probably) in `public function toUpper($plain){`, not in your `strtoupper()` code. If it's in a class, post the code that comes beforehand, if not in a class, remove `public`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: that function on a `class LayoutController extends BaseController
{` with many function , before this function also already there is `$ plain`, but no error, my goal to convert my data into all capital letters, `$ plain = column name`

Comment: Also - `strlen()` only has one parameter.

Comment: I just tried it and the error remains the same

Comment: Can you post the class please? There's probably an error before that code

Comment: `class LayoutController extends BaseController {` that is the class , and i can't copy all because many function on that class

Comment: Well then. Using an IDE and proper formatting might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of a function may only be specified for functions within a class. Either remove the `public` keyword to define a function outside of a class or move this code within a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

remove public if this function in not with in the Class
If in class please check for missing ";"

Comment: i just tried it but i have a new error `Method [toUpper] does not exist`

Comment: is this function is declared within the class? How you are accessing it?

Comment: yes , i accessing it in `$staging_db->vehicle_model      = $this->toUpper($item->vehicle_model);` in a same class,my goal to transform the data in that column on my databases into all capital letters